# Lambda@Edge URL redirect / path rewrite with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, regex, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I started learning NodeJS + Lambda@Edge a few days ago and one of the things that I was trying to do is the HTTP redirect/rewrite.

My current problem is when I try to use regex on the `destination`. For example, I want to redirect `https://example.com/pt-BR/blog-posts/....` to `https://example.com/pt/blog/....`, just rewriting the beginning of the `pathname`.

Is it possible to do this redirection? I know that I could do it via NGINX, but I was wondering if I could do the same via Lambda@Edge and more "dynamic", like getting these URLs via DynamoDB.

```
const redirects = require('./redirects.json').map(
  ({ source, destination }) => ({
    source: new RegExp(source),
    destination
  })
);

exports.handler = async event => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

  for (const { source, destination } of redirects) {
    if (source.test(request.uri)) {
      return {
        status: '301',
        statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
        headers: {
          location: [{ value: destination }]
        }
      };
    }
  }

  return request;
};
```

This is the `redirects.json`. The first two examples work perfectly, just the last one that is redirection to `https://example.com/pt/blog/$1` instead of `https://example.com/pt/blog/my-post-test001`.

```
[
  {
    "source": "^/pt/pt",
    "destination": "/pt/"
  },
  {
    "source": "^/en/en",
    "destination": "/en/"
  },
  {
    "source": "^/pt-BR/blog-posts/(.*)",
    "destination": "/pt/blog/$1"
  }
]
```

These are the examples/docs that I checked:
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/leveraging-external-data-in-lambdaedge/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-urlrewrite

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to rewrite a Cloudfront view request uri.  The right approach depends on whether the target of the rewrite is also a Cloudfront object in the distribution origin.  If it is, simply change the uri to the intended target.

1. Don't return a 301.
2. Alter request.uri with the rewrite uri path.
3. Add the context and callback parameters to the function (event, context, callback)
4. return the request object with callback(null,request);

Here is an example function that alters the uri of the cfrequest.  The callback returns the same cfrequest to a different uri.

Example with NodeJS: rewrite the uri '/posts/' to '/posts/index.html'

```
const DEFAULT_OBJECT = 'index.html';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const cfrequest = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  if (cfrequest.uri.length > 0 && cfrequest.uri.charAt(cfrequest.uri.length - 1) === '/') {
    // e.g. /posts/ to /posts/index.html
    cfrequest.uri += DEFAULT_OBJECT;
  }
  callback(null, cfrequest);
  return true;
};
```

Make sure to configure the Cloudfront behavior's viewer request with the rewrite Lambda@Edge function.  That's different than an origin request lambda function.

Link: [Hugo Quick Start, hosted on Cloudfront with lambda@edge](https://dev.to/starpebble/hosting-the-hugo-quickstart-project-on-aws-cloudfront-with-lambda-edge-5g5f)

That'll be one happy lambda function!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one for Node 12 that I use on [Svedig](https://svedig.com) to route `/session/My-Workout` to `/session/index.html`.

```
async function handler({ Records: [{ cf: { request } }] }) {
  const { uri } = request;
  if (uri.startsWith('/session/')) {
    return {
      ...request,
      uri: '/session/index.html',
    };
  }
  return request;
}

exports.handler = handler;
```

I would also recommend a Path Pattern of `session/*`.